# web api mvc knockout file upload with entity model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a web api 2 which return an entity set. In the entity set I have a property for an image url. When posting the model back using knockout I want to be able to upload a file. I have seen posts where the upload is done outside of the main post. However as the entity is database first I need to know how the post can send back the knockout view model data but also pass over the uploaded file which will then be saved to a local folder and the image url stored in the model.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using your DB entities tied to your ko model, or are you using a ViewModel?  Using a ViewModel, you should be able to handle that as relate it back to the DB entity.

Comment: I think you need to do this is two posts. First post the file and then post the json data.

Comment: ok so how would i setup the input to upload the file, this will then go to a controller which will return the url for where the file is and then this needs to update my viewmodel.